# Create a log in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, file, logging, status

There's two shells scripts: A.sh and B.sh

Another script C.sh will create a log containing:

- Host name
- User name
- Name of script
- Time at which the function was executed
- Description of function
- Status

```
Example:

<My hostname>
<My username>

A.sh
12:09:00 p.m "Initialize shell" OK
12:10:00 p.m. "Creating file" OK
12:11:00 p.m. "Creating backup" FAIL

B.sh
01:00:00 p.m "Initialize shell" OK
01:01:00 p.m. "Creating file" FAIL
01:02:00 p.m. "Creating backup" FAIL
```

The point is to obtain the success/failure status of each function and the time at which was executed and save it all to a log file. How do I check for the status of each function in a shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1Simplest way is flush output from scripts in independent files and then include this log files into common file, generated by C.sh.
You could use `tee` *nix function in A.sh, B.sh to populate log files and filter only records you need.
Also, it is possible to fetch errors in scripts via `set +o errexit` and `set +o pipefail`, and then check status of function executions right after the function:

```
set +o errexit
func.sh param1 param2
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "FAIL" | tee 1.txt
    exit 1 # if you need interrupt execution
else
    echo "OK" | tee 1.txt
fi
```